# Lock selected X/Wayland displays

Tags: x11, wayland

I have 3 monitors connected to my box.

What I'm looking for is to be able to lock two of them, and keep one running and having visible whatever is there.

Is there any solution that allows that? X preffered, but I'm willing to go Wayland if there is antyhing.

Comment: Run another X server on them?

Comment: I need it all under one display server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My use case is I'm using OBS wit monitor output as local output. I want to be able to lock the screen with OBS so nobody will mess with it while monitor output is still displaying whatever OBS puts there.